# How do you handle nested iframe/frame tags using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, frame

So I finally figured out on how to handle a single iframe using

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame("top")
```

and then turns out there is another iframe within this called "menu" (parent frame = "top" and child frame = "menu")

I can't use the same code above because it goes all the way back

I need to perform one action in the parent frame and another one in the child frame

how do i get this done ?

Answer (score 1):

Switch again to the child from the parent frame

```
driver.switch_to.frame("top")
# do something
driver.switch_to.frame("menu")
# do something
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle multiple nested [frame](/questions/tagged/frame) / [iframe](/questions/tagged/iframe) you have to induce *WebDriverwait* twice for `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()` to switch through the parent and child `frame` as follows:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
# SwitchTo parent frame = "top"
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"parent_iframe_css")))
# SwitchTo child frame = "menu"
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"child_iframe_css")))
```

> Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Answer (score -1):

Whenever dealing with nested frames, you have to find how many frames exist in the DOM element(From the developer console).
The easiest way to keep dealing with nested frames are FILO - Simply its like the First_In_Last_out. So once you loop into the frame that you want-Do necessary actions and then switch back frame by frame.

For instance......

```
driver.switch_to.frame("frame_1")
# All necessary actions
driver.switch_to.frame("frame_2")
# All necessary actions
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

I hope this helps you